# mongodb min/maxDistance on near command

Tags: mongodb

I run into several problem when using near query on collection.

I'm using 2dsphere index and want to get near places and paginate.
first thing that I note is that offset is not working on near. So this should be easy to emulate with min/maxDistance

But I can't figure out how to make working query minDistance nor maxDistance appear to be not working.

Here are commands that I'm using:

```
db.Place.runCommand({ "geoNear": "Place", "near": [ 49, 14 ], "spherical": true, "query": [ ], "distanceMultiplier": 6378.137, "minDistance": 60 });
db.Place.runCommand({ "geoNear": "Place", "near": [ 49, 14 ], "spherical": true, "query": [ ], "distanceMultiplier": 6378.137 });
db.Place.runCommand({ "geoNear": "Place", "near": [ 49, 14 ], "spherical": true, "query": [ ], "distanceMultiplier": 6378.137, "maxDistance": 60 });
```

1. when is set minDistace will output 0 results, it doesn't matter what number I input. Also in stats is nscanned 1, which is wrong and should be 299 which is number of documents in index.
2. and 3. will output 100 results both exactly same (this is also problem when serializing entity is large and 100 result which I don't need is slow) and nscanned is 299.

this is my index:

```
{ 
    "v" : 1, 
    "name" : "coordinates_2dsphere", 
    "ns" : "mydb.Place", 
    "sparse" : false, 
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

I'm using DoctrineODM and mongodb 3.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this query works only when GeoJson point is used.

documentation saying otherwise :( https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near

this is working command:

```
db.Place.runCommand({ "geoNear": "Place", "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 49, 14 ] }, "spherical": true, "query": [ ], "distanceMultiplier": 0.001, "maxDistance": 70000, "minDistance": 10000 });
```

only difference is that GeoJson works in meters.